# Variant of Japanese theorem for a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a convex cyclic quadrilateral, let $A', B', C', D'$ lie on angle bisector (all internal or all external) of $DAB$, $ABC$, $BCD$, $CDA$. Let $AA'B'B$ , $BB'C'C$, $CC'D'D$, $DD'A'A$ are cyclic quadrilateral then show that: $A'B'C'D'$ is a rectangle.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $ABA^\prime B^\prime$ is cyclic $$\angle AA^\prime B^\prime=\angle AB B^\prime=\angle B/2.$$ Similarly, since $ADA^\prime D^\prime$ is cyclic,
$$\angle AA^\prime D^\prime=\angle ADD^\prime=\angle D/2$$
it follows that
$$\angle D^\prime A^\prime B^\prime=\angle B/2+\angle D/2=90^\circ.$$
Similarly for the other angles.